"Access Denied' for SSH with port forwarding on Windows when it works fine if I use private address without port forwarding
On Windows 10, I had set up OpenSSH server.
In the firewall I allowed inbound port 22 like so:
New-NetFirewallRule -Name sshd -DisplayName 'OpenSSH SSH Server' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22 -Program "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sshd.exe"

When I use my private ip address with port 22 to access this server with ssh, it works.
After that I went to my router configuration to set up port forwarding so that port 22 of the public ip address would be forwarded to port 22 of the private ip address.
Trying ssh connection to port 22 of the public ip address via Putty gets me to ask for my password, so it seems the port forwarding worked.
However, when I enter my password it says "Access Denied".
For sanity check, I removed the port forwarding and again tried to ssh just with my private address and it sure works.
My hunch is that I need to do something extra on the Windows firewall but I'm not sure.

If it asks for a password, it seems the connection is coming through fine. It looks like your SSH server is configured to only allow local connections.

Post your OpenSSH configuration

Your public address shown by services like http://ipecho.net may or may not be the WAN address of your router. Please confirm the two addresses are the same. If they are not then you are probably behind CGNAT.

Are you attempting this from within your LAN? Perhaps your router doesn't do NAT hairpinning
